Master/Detail : when master scroll, is there an event called when all details have scrolled?
I have an app with one master and many detail queries (linked with MasterSource). I would like to do some calculations when the master record has scrolled and once all detail tables have scrolled too (precisely, I want to know if one of the details has records for this particular master record).
Using the OnAfterScroll event for the master fires too early. Is there a way around this?

I worked around the problem by using  System.Messaging to trigger the calculation from the detail's OnAfterScroll. Convoluted but it works. I'm still (very) open to a clean way of doing this.

You might tell us which Data Access Components (FireDAC, ADO, ...) you are using.

Not sure if this is relevant but I use Devart's PgDAC
